# Triggering live-reloading when developing an Ember addon

Tags: ember.js, ember-addon

I'm developing a private Ember addon for my team that will contain a few branded UI components that we will reuse in a bunch of different apps, such as a `<BrandHeader />` and `<BrandFooter />`.

Is there an standard for creating a development environment that allows you to get live-reloading previews of your components as you build them? If there's not a standard, does anyone have a workflow that you've created that works well for you?

I tried using the strategy of creating an addon with the ember-cli `ember addon <name>` and then `npm link`ing to an Ember app where I call the components, but with that method I need to rebuild the ember app every time I make a change in to the addon.

Comment: Hello, welcome! Yes this is supposed to work, but I think may need some config first (we don't want to always watch deps, or we'd have performance regressions!!)  -- what versions of ember-cli, ember-source, and ember-auto-import are you using? also, are you using embroider?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli I'm using ember-cli 5.1.0, ember-source 5.1.1, and ember-auto-import 2.6.3 in the addon project. In the app I was trying to link into, it's ember-cli 4.12.1, ember-source 4.12.0, and ember-auto-import 2.6.3. I'm not using Embroider in either project.

Also, I found out about the `test/dummy` app (see my self-answer), which is fine for my needs right now, but I can see the `npm link` strategy being useful in the future too, so I'd love to hear your advice still!

Comment: Thank for providing all that info!  glad you found a way to proceed! (and that you're using such new versions!!  ) but yeah, test/dummy is a good spot to put tests / demos / etc. 

I just posted an answer which you may or may not find useful that has the details that you may end up needing later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a place in the Ember documentation where this is clearly explained, but I found the answer:

**The `ember addon <name>` command automatically creates a "dummy" app in the `tests/dummy` directory.** You can use your addon components in this app with no special configuration. In the example below, I've just added the line where you see the `<BrandHeader>` component being called.

```
// tests/dummy/templates/application.hbs

{{page-title "Dummy"}}

<BrandHeader>Header text</BrandHeader>
<h2 id="title">Welcome to Ember</h2>

{{outlet}}
```

Running `ember serve` in the root folder of your project will start a development server like in a normal Ember app, serving the dummy app. Changes to components will live-update.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you'll want to look at to make sure that live-reload works between npm/yarn/pnpm link between projects:

In the v1 addon's `<project-root>/index.js`, you'll want to temporarily set `isDevelopingAddon`

```
module.exports = {
  name: require('./package').name,

  isDevelopingAddon: () => true,
}
```

if you have [Watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/) installed, you may be able to skip this step.

Next, in your app that you linked to, you *may* need to set `autoImport.watchDependencies` in your `ember-cli-build.js`, like this:

```
// In your ember-cli-build.js file
let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  autoImport: {
    watchDependencies: [
      // trigger rebuilds if "some-lib" changes during development
      'some-lib',
      // trigger rebuilds if "some-lib"'s inner dependency "other-lib" changes
      ['some-lib', 'other-lib'],
      // trigger rebuilds if any of your dependencies change during development
      ...Object.keys(require('./package').dependencies || {}),
    ],
  },
});
```

Under [embroider](https://github.com/embroider-build/embroider), I believe all this watching happens automatically.

Comment: Just noting in case anyone comes across this in the future while developing a v2 addon: After porting this addon to v2, I had to set `autoImport.watchDependencies` according to @NullVoxPopuli 's suggestion to get my test-app to observe changes to the addon